# Solr 4.4.0 atomic update always tries to create missing documents

Tags: solr, solr4

When I try to update a document with an index that doesn't exists, Solr answers with an error that explains that required fields are missing.
I presume that Solr tries to create the missing document from the atomic update. Is there any way to configure Solr so it will not attempt to create this document?

```
curl 'solr.local:8080/solr/update' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"800000","name":{"set":"Test"}}]'

{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":1},"error":{"msg":"[doc=800000] missing required field: candidate_source","code":400}}


Solr 4.4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is an option to ignore an update if the document does not exist.
Solr Internally still deletes and recreates the documents, that why you need to have the fields stored to be updatable.
So if the document does not exists, just that the delete would not happen.
However, the insert will lead to a failure if the document does not have the mandatory fields.

Answer (score -1):

check required attribute for the  field 'candidate_source' in schema.xml .

If the attribute required='true' then the field cannot go empty .

Remove the attribute required='true' for the field and try.